# Laravel Input Data To the Session When the User Did Not Fill Up The Required Field

Tags: php, laravel

I need the filled field remains its input data. but this happened it's gone. What should I do to make it still remain? I used Laravel 5.4. already used this command " $req->flash(); " but still failed

[Here is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3CEe.jpg)

**and this is my code:**

```
public function register_create(Request $req) {
        $req->flash();
        $req->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'matrix-number' => 'required',
        'ic-number' => 'required',
        'faculty' => 'required',
        'programme' => 'required',
        'part' => 'required',
        'group' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'phone-number' => 'required'
      ]);

      $name = Helpers::raw($req->input('name'));
      $matrix_number = $req->input('matrix-number');
      $ic_number = $req->input('ic-number');
      $faculty = Helpers::raw($req->input('faculty'));
      $programme = $req->input('programme');
      $part = $req->input('part');
      $group = $req->input('group');
      $email = $req->input('email');
      $phone_number = $req->input('phone-number');

      User::create([
        'name' => $name,
        'matrix_number' => $matrix_number,
        'ic_number' => $ic_number,
        'faculty' => $faculty,
        'programme' => $programme,
        'part' => $part,
        'group' => $group,
        'email' => $email,
        'phone_number' => $phone_number,
        'password' => $ic_number
      ]);
      {
        if (session('validate')) {
          $req -> validate;
        return redirect()->action('HomeController@login');
      }

       else

       {
         $req->session()->reflash();
         $req->session()->put('some_key', $req->all());
         return redirect()->back()->withInput();

       }
     }
   }
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/master/requests#old-input

Comment: I used that command, but it still missing from the form

Comment: Did you read the part about retrieving the data back out? `old('field_name')` should get it back out

Comment: yes, I did . should old and flash commands be combining?

Comment: I believe so, yes.